# Need to show data as table view in solaris

Tags: awk, solaris

I have below data named atp.csv file

```
Date_Time,M_ID,N_ID,Status,Desc,AMount,Type
2015-01-05 00:00:00 076,1941321748,BD9010423590206,200,Transaction Successful,2000,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 077,1941323504,BD9010423590207,351,Transaction Successful,5000,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 078,1941321743,BD9010423590205,200,Transaction Successful,1500,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 391,1941323498,BD9010500000003,200,Transaction Successful,1000,PRETOP
```

i used below command to count the result..

```
cat atp.csv|awk -F',' '{print $4}'|sort|uniq -c
```

the output is below.

```
3 200
1 351
```

but i want this output in a tabular view.. that is want to show this data as a table view. Is it possible??

Comment: And how should the table be formatted as. *that is want to show this data as a table view* is quite unclear. Provide some examples

Comment: as like there will be border around every data as like when we face the data from database table...

Comment: Please edit the question to add an example expected output. Also note that the entire command you have written can be replaced with a single `awk` command. and there is an unnecessary use of `cat`

Comment: yes i got. but can you please let me know is it possible to show the border around every data.....?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, a simple example like this: (see Notes at the end of the answer)

```
echo "3 200\n1 351"|awk -v t=7 
'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=t*NF+NF+1;i++)printf "-";print ""}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if(i==1)printf "|";
            fmt="%"t"s|"
            printf  fmt, $i
        }
        print ""
    }
    END{for(i=1;i<=t*NF+NF+1;i++)printf "-";print ""}'
```

this output

```
-----------------
|      3|    200|
|      1|    351|
-----------------
```

If you change the `-v t=20`, it outputs:

```
-------------------------------------------
|                   3|                 200|
|                   1|                 351|
-------------------------------------------
```

If you want a line after each row, that is, the border of each cell:

```
kent$  echo "3 200\n1 351"|awk -v t=20 
'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=t*NF+NF+1;i++)printf "-";print ""}
{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
                if(i==1)printf "|";
                        fmt="%"t"s|"
                        printf  fmt, $i
                }
                print ""
                for(i=1;i<=t*NF+NF+1;i++)printf "-"
                print ""
        }'
-------------------------------------------
|                   3|                 200|
-------------------------------------------
|                   1|                 351|
-------------------------------------------
```

#### Note

- there is no "autowrap" happening
- the above codes may fail if your output/file has empty fields or has different number of fields in each line. This part was not implemented.
- the `-v t=**` defines the width of each cell, it could be done *better (see next item)
- You have to give an **enough** `t` value to use this script. This could be done better, (I didn't do it). You can process the file/output twice, first round, find out the longest fields, so that we can get the `t` dynamically.
- further optimizing :  now each column has same width (`t`), you can in first round get the longest field in each column, so that make the column width different.